# could someone provide me sample codes how to connect DROPBOX to C# using DROPNET  so that i can get ideas how to use it

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I search all over the net, read forums but yet found none. i found this but it didn't explain from first till end i think it skips some important parts.

no headers. what headers to be used?

http://dkdevelopment.net/what-im-doing/dropnet/

Comment: Are you sure? They have a GitHub repository of samples: https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/tree/master/DropNet.Samples. Also, a project using Dropnet is open-source: https://www.transifex.net/projects/p/7Pass/. And 7Pass's homepage is: http://7pass.wordpress.com/. I found this in the same article.

Comment: @Jason: you might want to add this as an answer, I think it's as good as it gets.

Comment: If you ask more specific questions on the connection process, people can better help you. There are quite a few questions regarding DropBox (but sadly not Dropnet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424561/dropbox-api-user-token-user-secret. Your problems won't really be specific to Dropnet - it's just the weird lambda expressions and conceptual tokens you're having trouble with.

Comment: i read that also but no header?what header to be used? =<

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: sorry men still new to this ;(

Answer (score 2):

DropNet's Windows Phone 7 sample is in C#: https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet.Samples/DropNet.Samples.WP7/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: thanks. where can i find to manipulate dropbox like,create folder,add,edit,delete file to the folder and share? thanks man i will review this

Comment: The link you provided explains that (briefly with missing body parts to the code, though).

Comment: thank you. sorry for my ignorance. but you help me. this is for my future.